# Conflicto entre aws/aws-sdk-php y league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

Tags: laravel-8, aws

Tengo una aplicación en Laravel 8 y configuré `aws/aws-sdk-php` para enviara email con SES y todo estaba funcionando perfectamente hasta que instalé `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com";
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"> <Error> <Type>Sender</Type> <Code>AccessDenie (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): User `arn:aws:iam::684414359630:user/laravel_s3' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:sa-east-1:684414359630:identity/me@jhernandezch.com' - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"> <Error> <Type>Sender</Type> <Code>AccessDenied</Code> <Message>User `arn:aws:iam::684414359630:user/laravel_s3' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:sa-east-1:684414359630:identity/me@jhernandezch.com'</Message> </Error> <RequestId>1721b50a-14b8-43ef-ae8b-173a2de0f295</RequestId> </ErrorResponse>
```

Por lo que puedo entender es que al enviar un email `aws/aws-sdk-php` está tomando el usuario creado para  `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`.

En mi archivo `.env` están guardados las credenciales para las dos funcionalidades.

Para `aws/aws-sdk-php`

```
MAIL_MAILER=ses 
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 MAIL_USERNAME=AKIAZ6WSGLB----UNOF 
MAIL_USERNAME=AKIAZ6WS-----UNOF (Usuario email_laravel en IAM)
MAIL_PASSWORD=BMdl/Up2WPWOFpfX+fsDn------9luDWSrYWVFtmtHTkR/ 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls 
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=app@iuiui.com 
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Para `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAZ6WSG-----P4KH (Usuario Laravel_s3. en IAM)
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=vv3NnsRc1------u8h1Ie6XyQoQC5nFRYwk6nPC
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=sa-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=app-g12brasil-local
AWS_URL=https://app-g12brasil-local.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

Alguien podría indicarme porque `aws/aws-sdk-php` está tomando el `KEY_ID` de `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`, ya que en el error sale que el usuario "Laravel_S3" no está autorizado y ese usuario no es el que se configuró para enviar emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la definición de configuración para SES que se encuentra en [config/mail.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/926c48e8562e36811159d615ba27ebb2929d0378/config/mail.php#L48-L50) no se usan las llaves de correo que mencionas, a menos que estés usando SES via SMTP (pero en tu código estás usando credenciales IAM).

```
    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],
```

La verdadera configuración de SES está en [config/services.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/926c48e8562e36811159d615ba27ebb2929d0378/config/services.php#L27-L31). Ahí dice que el servicio SES utiliza justamente las credenciales que estás redefiniendo para S3

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
],
```

Para tu caso de uso me suena que lo más sano es definir la configuración de ses en `config/mail.php`

```
    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
        'key' => env('SES_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('SES_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('SES_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        'version' => 'latest',
    ],
```

y la de S3 en `config/filesystems.php`,

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('S3_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('S3_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('S3_AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

(usando un prefijo distinto para evitar alcance de nombres, de otra manera no tiene mucho sentido...)

Otra opción es que le des permiso en S3 y en SES al usuario IAM, pero tarde o temprano te encontrarás con un caso de uso donde tengas que separar los permisos y mientras más adelante ocurra más difícil será auditar dónde se usa qué.

Comment: It's works !!! Muchas gracias por tu explicación, modifiqué tal como sugeriste y funcionó perfectamente.